# How do you loop through a MYSQL table and use a value from each row to run a calculation row by row until row with right value is found?

Tags: php

How do you loop through a MYSQL table and use a value from each row to run a calculation row by row until row with right value is found?
i.e

```
 $records = mysqli_query($mysqli, "select * from TABLE");
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($records)) {
$valueA = $row['colA'];

// use $valueA as part a complex calculation
if ($valueA is the correct variable in this calculation) { 
// do something
}
else { //try next row }

elseif (// if all rows have been checked and no variable was useful) { 
// do something else
}
```

I know this is not the correct format for this code but I hope it explains what I am trying to do.
Thanks

Comment: So what's wrong with your code? Compare `$valueA` with that _certain condition_. Or add `WHERE` statement into your query

Comment: `else { //try next row }` makes little sense. You get access to the next row, in the next iteration of your loop - when `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($records)` has executed again. If you need to make any decision then based on what the _previous_ row contained - then use a flag for that, or something similar.

Comment: I think more information on the condition is required.

Answer (score 0):

User WHERE Statement inside your SQL.
Example:

```
SELECT name FROM customer WHERE id = 10;
```

**name** is what you want to select from table (basically that is your column)
**customer** is the table name
**id** is your search condition.